# Unwind nested lists using C# LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Let's say I have the following data,

```
data: {
    variations: [{
        steps: [
            { Name: "Crawl", Status: "Complete" },
            { Name: "Walk", Status: "InProgress" }
        ]
    },{
        steps: [
            { Name: "Crawl", Status: "Complete" },
            { Name: "Walk", Status: "Complete" },
            { Name: "Run", Status: "NotStarted" }
        ]
    }]
}
```

How would I arrive at this set of data using LINQ? The resulting set of data is the unique steps across all variations.

```
[
    { Name: "Crawl", Status: "Complete" },
    { Name: "Walk", Status: "InProgress" },
    { Name: "Walk", Status: "Complete" },
    { Name: "Run", Status: "NotStarted" }
]
```

I have tried many combinations of Select, but I'm having no luck.

Comment: Do you need to create all [combinations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination)  from some set of objects?

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45617525/mongodb-query-find-all-by-userid/45618622#45618622

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.SelectMany(..)`, and perform a `.Distinct(...)` to eliminate the second Crawl object.

```
var result = data
    .SelectMany(x => x.Steps)
    .Distinct()
    .ToArray();
```

This does require you to implement `IEquatable<T>` and override `.GetHashCode()` and `.Equals()`.

Answer (score 0):

For people, who do not want to implement Equals:

```
var result = data
        .SelectMany(x => x.Steps)
        .GroupBy(x => new { x.Name, x.Status })
        .Select(x => x.Key);
```