# MongoDB Query, find all by userID

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here is the structure of "customers" in my db

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "xxxxx"
    },
    "user": {
        "$oid": "xxxxx"
    },
    "name": "Test Mobile",
    "email": null,
    "phone": "xxxxx",
    "completed": false,
    "__v": 0
}
```

I am trying to query all customers with a certain userID and sort by "completed", I can get all customers like so

```
exports.list = function(req, res, next) {
  Customer.find().sort('-completed').exec(function(err, customers) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    return res.send(customers);
  })
};
```

I can query based on phone like so

```
exports.list = function(req, res, next) {
  Customer.find({ phone: "xxxxxxxx"}).sort('-completed').exec(function(err, customers) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    return res.send(customers);
  })
};
```

what I can't seem to do is query the userid, i tried this way and variations of this but no luck

```
exports.list = function(req, res, next) {
  Customer.find({"user.$oid": ObjectId("xxxxxxxxx")}).sort('-completed').exec(function(err, customers) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    return res.send(customers);
  })
};
```

Not sure if i'm missing something simple when querying ID's?

Comment: what is the error message from mongo ? or nothing is coming ?

Comment: Try `.find({"user": ObjectId("xxxx")})`

Comment: no error when I do it, when I try jcmetz way I get message: "ObjectId is not defined"}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
.find({user: xxxx)})
```

Without ObjectId