# Mongodb finding by ObjectId Do I use string or ObjectId in query?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Should I find a document with an ObjectId as primary key by going:

```
this._db
  .collection('users')
  .find({ _id: 'aaaaa0000000000000000000' })
  .toArray();
```

or

```
this._db
  .collection('users')
  .find({ _id: ObjectId('aaaaa0000000000000000000') })
  .toArray();
```

Comment: see this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45617525/mongodb-query-find-all-by-userid/45618622#45618622

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the second one will work:

```
this._db
 .collection('users')
 .find({ _id: ObjectId('aaaaa0000000000000000000') })
 .toArray();
```

Your question is not tagged Mongoose which provides the ability to query by string if desired. Pure Mongo requires you to use `ObjectId`.

Comment: Hey on a related question, if you have a document  with a property that links to the Id of another document, would you store that as ObjectId or just a string? Are their any benefits to indexing etc.

Comment: Store it as ObjectId. It takes up less space and is more efficient.